# What does it mean by "nobody ever measured"? Or what does "nobody ever measured" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In English Erotic movie "Fifty Shades Darker", *Ana* & *Christine* have conversation on bed after having sex.

> Christine: Why do you think you waited? For Sex.
>
> Ana: Mmm! Mmm! I was reading Austen and Brontë and **nobody ever measured**
>   up to that. I guess I was waiting for something exceptional. And then I
>   met you.

What does mean by "nobody ever measured" means?

Comment: the whole fragment is 'nobody ever measured up' - to measure up is to pass a test or criteria

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your highlighting has missed out an important word - **up**. According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/measure-up), **measure up** means

> to be good enough, or as good as someone or something else

The phrase **nobody ever measured up to that** means that nobody ever met that standard- presumably a standard set by characters in Austen and Brontë.